# Is it possible for widget to update when I access the app Icon for WidgetKit?

Tags: swift, swiftui, widgetkit

I've realized theres no way for the widget to be fully "live", since no matter how low of a number I put for my timeline, i noticed it udpates every like 5-10 minuite.

However, I was wondering if its possible to update the widget when the user access the app? I am trying to make the widget as consistent as possible. Thanks! :)

```
let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .after(Date()))
```

Comment: check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64134389/how-to-refresh-widget-when-main-app-is-used

Comment: The [Widget Code Along](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=yv6so7ie) might clear some stuff up for you they go through a lot of these concepts